# How can I modify my <textarea> html value based on user input

Tags: javascript, java

I have a html textarea element in my page where user gives comma separate values. for example below.
`A-48402,AA,SBAFL,AA+,USD,,`

From javascript (which I prefer) I am applying logic to check if the last row value is blank (separated by comma only) then to put a String value 'Y'. Thus I am writing the below

```
var data = document.getElementById('txid').value; 
rows = data.split('\n');var row1 = rows[0];row1Values=row1 .split(',');
```

Then I am applying logic to verify whether the last value for every row is blank or not, which is actually blank, then adding the below.

```
row_values.push('Y');
```

It is reflecting in debugger.

But what I see is the value 'Y' in the Java action class is not reflecting and showing usual 'Y' while the page submit.  How can I add this value 'Y' in every rows end (where there is blank) so that it will be visible in action class?

```
String Data = request.getParameter('mbs_inst_data');
```

This data is populated with the same blank values.

Comment: Put here <textarea> example with last row blank.

Comment: A-48402,AA,SBAFL,AA+,USD,, 
This is one row , The last value is only separated by comma i.e a blank value . I have to update blank value to Y ,like below 
A-48402,AA,SBAFL,AA+,USD,Y

Comment: Java and javascript are not related. I think you should remove the java tag.

Comment: @NomadMaker - there is both Javascript and Java in the question. The Java is on the server side receiving page request `request.getParameter(...)`

Comment: I see `row_values` mentioned only once, in `row_values.push(…)` so it's not clear what you are pushing that 'Y' into. In any case, what I see in your code is manipulating Javascript variables — initially populated from `txid` but never put back into the HTML element, so when that is submitted the textarea still contains the unmodified text. If you _are_ putting your altered data back into the textarea or form please show that.

Comment: Also, you say "check if the last **row** value is blank" but I think you mean the last _**column**_ value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this.

```
<p id="demo">Visit Microsoft! ,,</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
  var res = str.replace(/,,$/, ',Y');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

Output

```
Visit Microsoft! ,Y
```

I guess this would help you.

Comment: This would replace a set of two commas if they appeared in the middle of the string and *not* the final two commas, for example if the string was `str = "A-48402,AA,,SBAFL,AA+,USD,,"` then your str.replace produces `"A-48402,AA,YSBAFL,AA+,USD,,"` — a better replacement is `str.replace(/,,$/, ',Y')`

Answer (score 0):

If you're only checking for the last row then the only case that would happen is when it's ,,
so you can just do a simple check

```
let data = 'A-48402,AA,SBAFL,AA+,USD,,'
data = data.split(',')
let lastRowIsBlank = data[data.length-2] === ""
// we are doing length - 2 because in your situation we have 2 "" 
// since you have two commas. If you have only 1 comma we would 
// the same steps but with length - 1 
if(lastRowIsBlank) data[data.length-2] = "Y"
return data.toString()
```